# Disable write permission for etcd key?

Tags: etcd, etcdctl

I use `etcdctl put /my/branch/1 value123` to insert value into `/my/branch/1`. I want to remove write access for that `/my/branch/1` key using etcdctl, how can I do that?

Seems that `role grant-permission` or `revoke-permission` doesn't work, so I can still add values into that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer on your latest question about etcd and permissions. You have to have two type of clients: a) master TLS cert b) other TLS certs

To master you `grant-role root master` and therefore you have master client that can control etcd, whereas all other clients would have restricted access as you wish